# XGBoost use 3-Dimensional Input Containing Time Steps in Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, regression, xgboost

I am trying to train a `XGBRegressor` on time series data reshaped to have time steps, so the resulting shape of `X_train` can be something like `(12345, 5, 10)` if there are 12345 samples, 10 features and a time step of 5.

However, when we try to train `XGBRegressor` using such a training data,

```
import xgboost as xgb
xgb = xgb.XGBRegressor()
xgbr.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

we get the error

> ValueError: ('Expecting 2 dimensional numpy.ndarray, got: ', (12345, 5, 10))

What is the correct way of training `XGBRegressor` on training data containing time steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As clear from the error, you cannot directly fit and [`XGBRegressor`](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html) with a 3D shaped array. Recurring to ML for time series problem *is* quite common, though you have to make sure you are feeding the regressor meaningful features, that capture the time dependency between samples.

So something you could start with for your particular problem, is to create a new feature indicating to which time step a sample belongs. That way, the decision trees will also learn the effect the time-dependant variable has in the target variable. Though the more meaningful features you can add the better, so you could also consider including features capturing other possible time-dependant statistics.

Comment: Awesome, in addition to the new feature indicating the timestep of a sample, will you suggest adding a second new feature indicating the sample's position in that timestep? Is it correct to say that following your suggestion, we will be transforming the data from `(12345, 5, 10)` to `(12345 * 5, 10+1)`?

Comment: Yes that is exactly the idea @Nyxynyx so a new row for each timestamp plus the additional time-stamp feature. And yes, if the position in the times can be a relevant predictor, indeed it makes sense to ad it as a feature

Comment: After converting the training data from `(12345, 5, 10)` to `(12345 * 5, 10+1)`, we now have 5 times as many training samples (and hence predictions) than labels. How should we handle the shortage of labels?

Comment: Are you using XGBoost to try and forecast the time series specifically? Or are you trying to conduct classification/regression where the data just happens to be time series?

Comment: IIUC all new samples should share the label corresponding to the original array. That is, if the original order is preserved, the labels should be `np.repeat(y,5)` @Nyxynyx

Comment: @MichaelGrogan Trying to use XGBoost to forecast the time series. Every training sample is trained to predict a value that occurs one time period ahead.

Comment: XGBoost can work, although it is a machine learning approach and not specifically designed for long-term forecasts. You could always compare your results with ARIMA and see which one works better.