# Converting [samples, time-steps, features] into 2D input shape

Tags: python, input, lstm, sequence, xgboost

I have a 3D input sequence prepared for LSTM, i.e., (samples, time-steps, features) or (100,20,5) for instance. And I want to compare the LSTM results with XGBoost which can only take 2D input.
The confusion is whether I should reshape the 3D array into:

1. (100, 20*5), no changes for the y labels shape.
2. (100*20, 5), make changes to y labels shape using np.repeat(y,20), as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61550147/xgboost-use-3-dimensional-input-containing-time-steps-in-python/61550487#61550487)

Which one is the correct way to represent the input shape for XGBoost training?

At the moment I have tried step 1 by flattening the time steps with the features. But I am not 100% certain if this is the correct way, if whether we should treat the XGBoost training data set independently for each sample as step 2.